# How to name a JSON object and writing it into a .json file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I tried to create an empty json variable like this;

```
var myJSON = {
measurements: {} };
```

and below, I tried to push data into json and write that json into chart.json file but there is an error occured:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object

```
connection.query('SELECT Temprature,Humidity, Time from miTemp1', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    let i = 0, j = 0;
    console.log(typeof (results))
    while (i < results.length) {
        let myDate = new Date(results[i].Time * 1000);
        // console.log('Temp: ' + results[i].Temprature, 'Humidty:' + results[i].Humidity, 'Time: ' + myDate.toLocaleString());
        measurements[i] = results[i];
        i += 510;
        j++;
    }
    myJSON.measurements = JSON.stringify(measurements);
    console.log(typeof(myJSON));
    console.log(myJSON);
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString() + '  Number of measurement: ' + j);
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync('./chart.json', myJSON);
        console.log("JSON data is saved.");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

If I create json variable like `var myJSON = {}` there is no problem. Why this is happening? Thanks for helps ^-^

EDIT:

here is my JSON's data.

```
{
"0": {
    "Temprature": 25.88,
    "Humidity": 43,
    "Time": 1628164626
},
"510": {
    "Temprature": 26.22,
    "Humidity": 45,
    "Time": 1628169522
},
```

SOLUTION:
All I need to do is changing `myJSON.measurements = JSON.stringify(measurements);` to `myJSON.measurements = measurements;` and stringify the entire object.

Comment: can you share the value of `myJSON`

Comment: Why did you use: ` myJSON.measurements = JSON.stringify(measurements);` instead of stringifying the entire object? I think you need to do something like: `const myJSONText= JSON.stringify(myJSON);` and write `myJSONText` to your file

Comment: I would try to populate it like `myJSON.measurements[i] = results[i];` without stringify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just write an object to a file. You need to serialize it first with `JSON.stringify()`:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('./chart.json', JSON.stringify(myJSON));
```

You also don't need to serialize the `measurements` property, since you serialize the whole object. You can replace this:

```js
myJSON.measurements = JSON.stringify(measurements);
```

with this:

```js
myJSON.measurements = measurements;
```

Comment: just to add something, maybe you wanted to use ```myJSON.measurements``` and noy ```myJSON```. I say that because the attribute is stringified but as said not the object ;)

Comment: I made it "myJSON.measurements = JSON.stringify(measurements);", when I serialize it again, the json doesn't get filled properly.

Comment: @atarikaltun Then don't serialize the measurements property, only serialize the whole object.

Comment: @atarikaltun What format are you expecting the final JSON to be?

Comment: I think the first ```myJSON.measurements = JSON.stringify(measurements);``` is a bad idea since you want the whole object into json, if you do it twice you will have to JSON.parse the object and then do it again for measurement

Comment: @AbdElbeltaji I want my json object has property named measurements

Comment: @atarikaltun Then reomve the line ` myJSON.measurements = JSON.stringify(measurements); `  and use the solution above.

Comment: @AbdElbeltaji thanks a lot, all I had to do is `myJSON.measurements = measurements` and serializing the whole myJSON. Thank you all so much